# .FillRectangle not drawing anything

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d

I'm having trouble figuring out why .FillRectangle is not working for me.

Furthermore, as it's not thorwing any exception, I ran out of ideas why it could be, so I need some help here:/

The part of the code affected is this

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024))
        {
            String line;
            int mW = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(this.Size.Width / 2d));
            int mH = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(this.Size.Height / 2d));
            SolidBrush myBrush;
            myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            PointF A = new PointF(0f, 0f);
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.TranslateTransform(mW, mH);
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] points = line.Split(',');
                A = new PointF((float)(Convert.ToDecimal(points[0])), ((float)(Convert.ToDecimal(points[1]))));
                //A is defined correctly, as A.X and A.Y both have values
                g.FillRectangle(myBrush, A.X, A.Y, 1f, 1f);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception p)
{
    MessageBox.Show(p.Message);
}
```

Any help would be supper appreciated, as my knowledge about Grpahics is **very limited**

Thanks in advance,

Rubén :)

Comment: Is this condition ever met? `while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok, that helped a lot :D. Thanks!

Posting comment as an Answer then:

`this.CreateGraphics` is the likely culprit. This draws to a temp surface that gets erased when the Form refreshes. Either use `e.Graphics` in the Paint() Event, or draw to a Bitmap with `Graphics.FromImage()` and display that.